# POST request with REST::Client

Tags: json, rest-client

I am creating a POST request using REST::Client and keep getting following error:

Response:Not a SCALAR reference at   /nethome/perl5/lib/perl5//LWP/Protocol/http.pm line 254, <IFH> line 1.

My code Snippet:

```
use warnings;
use diagnostics; 
use strict; 
use JSON::MaybeXS;
use REST::Client;

my $host = 'myurl';
my $hashref = {};
my $jsonEncode=JSON::MaybeXS->new->utf8(1)->pretty(1);
```

Inside a Subroutine, using while loop

```
my @fields=split("\t",$_); 
my $sample_id=$fields[0];
my $chr=$fields[1];
my $position=$fields[2];
my $alt=$fields[5];
my $hashref =("variant_request"=>{"searchParameters"=>{"sampleIds"=> ["$sample_id"],"genome"=>[{"loci"=>{"chromosome"=>"$chr","position"=>$position,"allele"=>"$alt"}}]}});
push (@meta,\%hashref);
printQuery (@meta,$encoded);
```

Inside PrintQuery Subroutine:

```
    my $filename =$_[1];
    my $hash = $jsonEncode->canonical->encode($_[0]);
    $client->POST($hash,{'Content-Type'=>'application/json','Accept'=>'application/json'});
    print 'Response:'.$client->responseContent()."\n";
    print 'Response Status:'. $client->responseCode()."\n";
```

Input:

```
601     1       114872280       rs544699256     A       G
```

Answer (score 0):

So not exactly sure why this worked:
Changed This:

```
my $client=REST::Client->new(host=>$host);
```

To:

```
my $client=REST::Client->new();
```

Added:

```
my $url = 'myurl';
```

And Finally changed:

```
$client->POST($url,$jsonrequest,{'Content-Type'=>'application/json','Accept'=>'application/json'});
```